# Making c++ compiler optimize to call constructor once in map initialization

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a function that generates a map to object of type A.

```
map<int,A> test()
{
    map<int, A> m;
    A a1(10); // constructor
    A a2(20);
    A a3(30);
    m[0] = a1; m[1] = a2; m[2] = a3; // <-- copy constructor and = operator
    return m;
}
```

When I execute this function, I have constructor called, and then copy constructor and = operator called.

```
map<int,A> x = test();
```

Is there a way to make compiler optimize this to call only one constructor like Return Value Optimization (RVO) does?

Alternative approach might be using pointer, but I'd like to know if there's another way.

```
map<int,A*> test3()
{
    map<int, A*> m;
    A* a1 = new A(10);
    A* a2 = new A(20);
    A* a3 = new A(30);
    m[0] = a1; m[1] = a2; m[2] = a3;
    return m;
}

...

map<int,A*> x = test3();

...

for (auto val: x)
{
    delete val.second;
}
```

Comment: You could do `return {{0, A{10}}, {1, A{20}}, {2, A{30}}};`.

Comment: you should pass the map by reference, that will avoid a copy outside.

Answer (score 1):

If your implementation supports it, [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A(int) { std::cout << "ctor\n"; }
    A(const A&) { std::cout << "copy ctor\n"; }
    A(A&&) { std::cout << "move ctor\n"; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; }
};

std::map<int,A> test()
{
    std::map<int, A> m;
    m.emplace(0, 10);
    m.emplace(1, 20);
    m.emplace(2, 30);
    return m;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, A> m = test();
    std::cout << "m.size() = " << m.size() << '\n';
}
```

output:

```
$ ./test
ctor
ctor
ctor
m.size() = 3
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tested with smart pointer, and it seems fine with me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    int x;
public: 
    A() {
        cout << "Default constructor called" << endl;
    }  
    A(const A& rhs) 
    {
        this->x = rhs.x;
        cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;
    }
    A& operator=(const A& rhs)
    {
        this->x = rhs.x;
        cout << "Copy constructor called" << endl;
    }
    A(int x) : x(x) {
        cout << "*I'm in" << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "*I'm out" << endl;
    }
    int get() const {return x;}
    void set(int x) {this->x = x;}
};

std::map<int,unique_ptr<A>> test()
{
    std::map<int, unique_ptr<A>> m;
    m[0] = unique_ptr<A>(new A(101));
    m[1] = unique_ptr<A>(new A(201));
    m[2] = unique_ptr<A>(new A(301));
    return m;
}

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    auto m = test();
    for (const auto& i: m)
    {
        cout << i.second->get() << endl;
    }    
}
```

Result:

```
*I'm in
*I'm in
*I'm in
101
201
301
*I'm out
*I'm out
*I'm out
```